# Can't get one div completely to the right

Tags: html, css

I am looking for help regarding a `<div>` problem. In the header section I have a logo, facebook (button) and my menu. The facebook button and the logo are in the right place, however I cannot manage to get the menu in the right place. I want to it to be to the right side, sticking to the right side of the browser.

I hope someone is willing to help me.

```
<div id="topContainer">
    <div id="centerContainer">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo fl"><img src="images/logoMAIN.png" alt="Grand Cafe de Reebok" /></a>

        <div id="social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GrandCafeDeReebok?fref=ts"><img src="images/Facebook.png" /></a>
        </div> <!-- End social -->          

        <div id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>de Reebok</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="reserveer.html"><span>Reserveer</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="openingstijden.html"><span>Openingstijden</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="arrangement.html"><span>Arrangement</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="fotos.html"><span>Foto's</span></a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div> <!-- End navigation -->
    </div> <!-- End centerContainer -->
</div> <!-- End topContainer -->
```

The CSS file:

```
#centerContainer {
width: 100%;
height: 280px;
margin: 0 auto;}

.logo {
float: left; 
margin: 58px 36px 33px 85px;
display: block;
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 180px;}

#social {
float: right;
margin: 20px 30px 0 0;}

#navigation ul li {
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px; 
text-align: center;}

#navigation ul li a {
margin-right: 18px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: 3px;}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
color: #fff;}

#navigation ul li.active a {
color: #fff;}

#navigation {
float: right;
margin: 90px 0px 77px 0px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
width: 680px; 
padding: 15px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
clear: both;}

#mainContainer {
background-image: url(../images/mainContainer-bg.png);
padding-top: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
height: 462px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 40px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 40px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 12px 40px -6px black;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and people will help more.

Comment: You did not specify what "the right place" means.  So you want the logo flush left and the navigation flush right.  Where does the Facebook button go? Unless you meant, logo flush left, FB button flush right, and then the navigation starts on a new line but flush right?

Comment: @MarcAudet: Based on this statement in question *I want to it to be to the right side, sticking to the right side of the browser*, I think the user wants the latter option mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @Harry Not clear what the OP wants, maybe the navigation is supposed to stretch from the right edge of the logo to the right edge of the page? who knows... no feedback yet.

Comment: @MarcAudet: Yup agreed :)

Comment: @MarcAudet: thanks for your feedback thus far. The div supposed to have a width of 680px and has to stick to the right side of the browser. Taking this as the starting point is has to stretch 680px to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#navigation` element already has `float: right` and `position: absolute`. So just adding `right: 0px` should be enough.

```
#navigation {
    float: right;
    right: 0px; /*Added this line*/
    margin: 90px 0px 77px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
    width: 680px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/944tX/)

Comment: Thanks! Next time I will use Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try below styles:

```
 #navigation{
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px; /* According to your needs*/
 }
```

Now navigation will always stick to right side of screen